# ePub reader with node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, epub

I am currently making an ePub reader for the backend with NodeJs. Basic CRUD and Auth functions are implemented. If I upload the ePub file, can I store it in MongoDB? Currently, I have an ePub sample file. I want to read this in the console and then pass it to the front-end, but I don't know how to start. Is there a good example?

Comment: best to keep files out of the db and store on local drive.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/profullstack/upvotocracy-api/blob/master/controllers/uploads.js